# Unflatten nested data from join query

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a series nested objects that are contained in a relational database represented by one-to-many relationships.

[image]

Given a result set from a join query such as the following where obj A contains many Bs which in turn contain many Cs which in turn contain many Ds. Here is the query:

```
SELECT A_ID AS A, B_ID AS B, C_ID AS C, D_ID AS D FROM A 
INNER JOIN B on B.A_ID = A.A_ID 
INNER JOIN C ON C.B_ID = B.B_ID
INNER JOIN D ON D.C_ID = C.C_ID
```

The results of this query are as follows:

```
| A | B | C | D |
|---|---|---|---|
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
```

I want to generate a JSON object like this. Note that there is only one A object, the data is the same in each row due to the inner join. The A object contains two B objects. The first B contains two Cs and the second B contains only one C which contains two Ds. The only unique data really is D but each row contains all the data from the hierarchy:

```
{
  "A": {
    "A_id": 1,
    "Bs": [{
        "B_id": 1,
        "Cs": [{
            "C_id": 1,
            "Ds": [{
                "D_id": 1
              }]
          },{
            "C_id": 2,
            "Ds": [{
                "D_id": 2
              }]
          }]
      },{
        "B_id": 2,
        "Cs": [{
            "C_id": 3,
            "Ds": [{
                "D_id": 3
              },{
                "D_id": 4
              }]
          }]
      }]
  }
}
```

What is the simplest and most efficient way to do this in javascript? Note, simplest may involve the use of a library such as underscore.js or lodash.

The data already comes back in a form such as:

```
[{A_id:1, B_id:1, C_id:1, D_id:1},{...}]
```

Comment: personally I'm not seeing the relationship between input and output. Clarification would help

Answer (score 0):

So this is how we approached it:

```
var A = { Bs: []};
var Bs = {};
var Cs = {};
var Ds = {};

_.each(results, function(r) {
    var B = Bs[r.B_ID];
    if(!B) {
        B = {id: r.B_ID, Cs:[]};
        A.Bs.push(B);
        B[r.B_ID] = B;
    }
    var C = Cs[r.C_ID];
    if(!C) {
        C = {id: r.C_ID, D:[]};
        B.Cs.push(C);
        Cs[r.C_ID] = C;
    }
    var D = Ds[r.D_ID];
    if(!D) {
        D = {id: r.D_ID};
        C.Ds.push(D);
        Ds[r.D_ID] = D;
    }
}
```